# Ununtu 16.10 no internet, wi-fi or cable

Tags: internet

i just installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my laptop, but i can not connect to internet, wi-fi or cable, it just not working. i hope that you can help me, thanks!

the output of: `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'`

[image]

Comment: It is not a good idea to install non-LTS releases for a newbie. You can install 16.04 LTS.

Comment: i tried with 16.04, but i had exactly same problem so i decided to try another version.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Comment: there you go! http://i64.tinypic.com/1zv3k3l.jpg

Comment: Please [edit] your question for new information, do not post it to comments. Anyway this screenshot does not add anything useful.If you want help, post the output of above mentioned terminal command.

Comment: Is your system 64 or 32-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another computer to download these files:

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu14_all.deb

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.042.00-2_all.deb

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb

Copy the files to your Ubuntu Home folder and run in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Reboot. Both interfaces should work. If you have UEFI, you need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS first.

Comment: so with that method i fixed the wi-fi connection, but the cable internet still not working!

Comment: "The cable internet" is too broad. I suggest asking a new question with explanation what is your internet connection.

Comment: Isn't the Realtek driver unsigned? If so, you may need to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: It looks like there is no SB. `wl` has been installed successfully.